# How to disable hovering in QComboBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, qcombobox

I have written a custom combo box in order to be able to select many items. The selected items changes its color, but the hovering changes color as well, so you cannot say if the item that is hovered over, is selected or not.
Is it possible to disable the the hovering effect?

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: I have solved the problem by setting the following stylesheet:
QListWidget::item:hover {
    background: transparent;}